# What is a simple and secure way to transmit a login key from one website to another while redirecting a user?

Tags: security, architecture, encryption, user-management

I want to create a portal website for log-in, news and user management.  And another web site for a web app that the portal redirects to after login.

One of my goals is to be able to host the portal and web-app on different servers.  The portal would transmit the user's id to the web-app, once the user had successfully logged in and been redirected to the web app.  But I don't want people to be able to just bypass the login, or access other users accounts, by transmitting user ids straight to the web app.

My first thought is to transmit the user id encrypted as a post variable or query string value.  Using some kind of public/private key scenario, and adding a DateTime stamp to key to make it vary everytime.

But I haven't done this kind of thing before, so I'm wondering if there aren't better ways to do this.

(I could potentially communicate via database, by having the portal store the user id with a key in a database and passing that key to the web app which uses it to get the user id from that database.  But that seems crazy.)

Can anyone give a way to do this or advice?  Or is this a bad idea all-together?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you are asking for a single-sign-on solution. What you describe sounds a lot like [SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language), although SAML is a bit more advanced ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how secure you want this entire thing to be. Generating an encrypted token with embedded timestamp still leaves you open to spoofing - if somebody steals the token (i.e. through a network sniffing) he will be able to submit his own request with the stolen token. Depending on the time to live you will give your token this time can be limited, but a determined hacker will be able to do this. Besides you cannot make time to live to small - you will be rejecting valid requests.
Another approach is to generate "use once" tokens. This is 'bullet proof' in terms of spoofing, but it requires coordination among all the servers within the server farm servicing your app, so that if one of them processed the token the other ones would reject it. 
To make it really secure for the failover scenarios, etc. it would require some additional steps, so it all boils down to how secure you need it to be and how much you want to invest in building it up

Comment: The encrypted token should be as secure as your referring website's private key.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at [SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language)

Answer (score 1):

PGP would work but it might get slow on a high-traffic site

One thing I've done in the past is used a shared secret method. Some token that only myself and the other website operator knows concatenated to something identifying the user (like their user name), then hash that with a checksum algorithm such as SHA256 (you can use MD5 or SHA1 which usually are more available but they are much easier to break)

The other end should do the same thing as above. Take the passed identifying information and checksum it. Compare that to the passed checksum, if they match the login is valid.

For added security you could also concat the date or some other rotating key. Helps to run SSL on both sides as well.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the answer resides somewhere in `SHA256 / MD5 / SHA1` plus shared secret based on human actually has to think. If there is money somewhere, we may assume there are no limits to what some persons will do - I ran with [ a person ] in High School for a few months to observe what those ilks will do in practice. After a few months, I learned not to be running with those kind. Tediously avoiding work, suddenly at 4 AM on Saturday Morning the level of effort and analytical functioning could only be described as "Expertise" ( note capitalization ) There has to be a solution else sites like Google and this one would not stand the chance of a dandelion in lightning bolt.

There is a study in the mathematical works of cryptography whereby an institution ( with reputable goals ) can issue information - digital cash - that can exist on the open wire but does not reveal any information. Who would break them? My experience with [ person ] 
shows that it is a study in socialization, depends on who you want to run with. What's the defense against sniffers if the code is already available more easily just using a browser?

```
<form type="hidden" value="myreallysecretid">
```

vis a vis

```
<form type="hidden" value="weoi938389wiwdfu0789we394">
```

So which one is valuable against attack? Neither, if someone wants to snag some Snake Oil from you, maybe you get the 2:59 am phone call that begins: "I'm an investor, we sunk thousands into your website. I just got a call from our security pro ....." all you can do to prepare for that moment is use established, known tools like SHA - of which the 256 variety is the acknowledged "next thing" - and have trace controls such that the security pro can put in on insurance and bonding.

Let alone trying to find one who knows how those tools work, their first line of defense is not talking to you ... then they have their own literature - they will want you to use their tools.

Then you don't get to code anything.